# How to how to avoid duplicated code in if/else statement?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have two exactly the same logic in if/else statement:

```
    if alert.get('comment_time_created') is None:
 here-> args = {'is_comment_visible': 1, 'comment_time_created': current_comment_time}
        await self._db_alert.update_alert(alert['alert_id'], **args)
    else:
        first_comment_time_creation = datetime.strptime(alert['comment_time_created'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        current_comment_time = datetime.strptime(current_comment_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        if current_comment_time > first_comment_time_creation:
            await self._db_alert.update_alert(alert['alert_id'], is_comment_visible=1)
        else:
 here->     args = {'is_comment_visible': 1, 'comment_time_created': current_comment_time}
            await self._db_alert.update_alert(alert['alert_id'], **args)
```

Is there any way to do this logic once?

Comment: Can't you just save that dictionary in a variable above?

Comment: This might be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Carcigenicate could you explaine please how to do this?

Comment: @ipetr Above the `if alert.get` at the top, can't you just write `args = {'is_comment_visible': 1, 'comment_time_created': current_comment_time}`, and remove the other `args` lines?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, thanks!! but the problem still exists: `await self._db_alert.update_alert(alert['alert_id'], **args)` this line is duplicated

Comment: @ipetr The `await` lines could probably be removed too by making a function. I've never used `await` before though; I didn't know python even had such a keyword.

Comment: I think `await` showed up in 3.5:  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to do the await line on every condition, just your kwargs are changing where you dont have `comment_time_created` arg for one particular condition. This can be reduced to:

```
args = {'is_comment_visible': 1}
if alert.get('comment_time_created') is None:
    args['comment_time_created'] = current_comment_time
else:
    first_comment_time_creation = datetime.strptime(alert['comment_time_created'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    current_comment_time = datetime.strptime(current_comment_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    if current_comment_time <= first_comment_time_creation:
        args['comment_time_created']= current_comment_time

await self._db_alert.update_alert(alert['alert_id'], **args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the dict. Call the method only after the end of the outer if. Simplify the block by ripping the expressions that are common to all branches.
Something like this:

```
if alert.get('comment_time_created') is not None:       
    first_comment_time_creation = datetime.strptime(alert['comment_time_created'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    current_comment_time = datetime.strptime(current_comment_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    if current_comment_time <= first_comment_time_creation:
        comment_time_created = current_comment_time

await self._db_alert.update_alert(alert['alert_id'], is_comment_visible = 1, comment_time_created = comment_time_created)
```

Comment: Incorrect. He seems to have `current_comment_time` defined before the first condtion, check his first initialization of args

Comment: Well spotted. Just have to remove the first declaration.

Comment: local variable `comment_time_created ` might be referenced before assignment

Comment: I know it might. But as the @MohitC said, I'm assuming he already assigned a default value.